# Bower install command doesn't work

Tags: powershell, bower

I've got a problem when I want to install a package using Bower. I wanted to install jQuery using this command:

```
bower install jquery
```

But unfortunately it threw this error:

```
bower EINVALID      Name must be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes, "@" or spaces
```

Then I tried some other Bower commands and when I'm trying to use for example

```
bower version
```

it throws the exactly same error. What is interesting though, the Bower commands work if I type them into PowerShell which I opened as administrator. I'm using Node.js v6.2.1 and Bower v1.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

I see this behavior when I do not have a `bower.json` file.  After creating that file, this problem goes away.  It is still a bug in bower, because I cannot even run `bower init` to create the file, I have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same error recently, and what fixed it for me was rolling back to bower v1.3.9

Try this: `npm install -g bower@1.3.9`